# webpack-dev-server.watchContentBase doesn't watch all files inside content base

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would appreciate if someone could explain to me why webpack-dev-server doesn't reload browser page on **home.html** code change, yet reload gets triggered on home.js or index.html code change.

**Simplified version of project structure -**

```
/app
  -app.js
  -index.html
  /core
    -home.html
    -home.js (imported in app.js)
  /dist
    -app.bundle.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './app'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        watchContentBase: true
    }
}
```

I'm using webpack@3.7.1 and webpack-dev-server@2.11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You was pretty close, just add to `contentBase` every folder that contains `.html` files:

```js
devServer: {
  contentBase: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'app/core'),
    // and so on...
  ],
}
```